# How to encrypt a dynamic form with Adobe Livecycle?

Tags: encryption, adobe, certificate, livecycle, dynamic-forms

I want to encrypt a dynamic form with Adobe livecycle ES 2. I do it like it is described here

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/index.htm?content=000819.html

and I get the Exception: ALC-ENC-100-015 Can not encrypt reader extended document.

My use case requires the form to be dynamic, since the user has to enter data and send it back to a server.

How can I encrypt a dynamic form with certificates?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Cheers,

Arne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Look here how to do it.

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/833504